# how to integrate WebSphere Commerce Build and Deployment tool with JaCoCo

Tags: jacoco

I'm new to WebSphere Commerce Build and Deployment tool and I want to integrate WCBD with JaCoCo for the code coverage and the final .exec file should be picked up by Sonar-runner.

Kindly help me here

Thanks in advance !